# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow - TweetSharp

Tags: twitter, tweetsharp

Code:

```
TwitterService twitter = new TwitterService(oauth_consumer_key, oauth_consumer_secret);
twitter.AuthenticateWith(oauth_consumer_key, oauth_consumer_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret);
TwitterSearchResult res = twitter.Search(new SearchOptions { Q = hashtag, Count = 10, MaxId = max_id });
```

Error:

```
   Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow
```

Stacktrace:

```
at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.Int32Parse(Char[] chars, Int32 start, Int32 length)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumber()
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsInt32Internal()
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsInt32()
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
```

I want to get all the tweets with particular keyword in it. Sometimes the response is proper while sometime i get this error.